# Adding segment controller on navigation bar in the second row

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to add a segment controller to the navigation bar **not as the title**, but like this: [image]

How can I do that?

Comment: This is exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21999916/4936853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it looks like this uses the navigation bar's title, which is actually in the same place as where you want your segmented control to go. Instead, you need to add a "prompt" to the navigation bar to increase the height of the bar, and add the prompt text above the content area of the bar.

This can be done purely in Interface Builder as illustrated by the screenshot below, or programmatically using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setPrompt:@"some prompt text"];
```

[image]

Comment: But what about "Done" button? :)

Comment: I can't get this to work in code (iOS 7, Storyboards)—do you put that line in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, ...? In the containing view controller, the contained view controller...?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do the same and simply added the segmented control inside a view added under the navigationbar bottom.