# UIToolbar shadow doesn´t hide when bar position is UIBarPositionTopAttached

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have a container view with two views and a toolbar. In the `ContainerViewController` I have "deactivated" the shadow of the navigation bar using this code (from Apple's library):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentPixel"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pixel"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Also I have implemented the `UIToolbarDelegate` and its method

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar 
{
    return UIBarPositionTop; //or return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

But the shadow of the toolbar is still between the navigation bar and the toolbar and not underneath the toolbar, to separate the toolbar from the content.

Any ideas why the shadow doesn't change? Or how to check, if the toolbar position is position really TopAttached.

**Edit:**

I try to do something like described in this post: [UISegmentedControl below UINavigationbar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887252/uisegmentedcontrol-below-uinavigationbar-in-ios-7) without the searchbar.
As explained there, there are two shadows, the one of the navigationbar in the navigationcontroller, that is between navbar and toolbar. And the shadow of the toolbar.
I was able to deactivated the shadow of the navigationbar as described. It works also in the `viewDidLoad:`

But the shadow of the toolbar is in the wrong position. Using the `positionForBar:` method it should be in the button of the toolbar, but it stays in the top (between Navbar and Toolbar).

So I am looking for the fault, why it does not change.

Comment: in what method are you trying to change the shadow?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what method you tried to change the shadow in, but I'm going to guess that you're trying to do it in `viewDidLoad:`

Your `navigationBar` does not actually exist in `viewDidLoad`, instead change the shadow in `viewWillAppear:` like this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparentPixel"]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pixel"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];     
}
```