# Adding UISegmentedControl below navigation bar with UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have to implement the following layout:

[image: Header]

For this, I have the following constraints:

- UINavigation bar should be the system's because every other imitation looks ugly
- UISegmentedControl should be placed inside the navigation bar
- the segmented control should be placed below the navigation buttons
- I have to use UISearchDisplayController to have the system default search look & feel
- For the UISearchDisplayController to work I have to have UITableViewController, because it does not work with a simple UIViewController

I have found several solutions for something similar ([like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887252/uisegmentedcontrol-below-uinavigationbar-in-ios-7)), but they either use `UIToolbar`/`UIView` (which I can't add to my controller, because all `UITableViewController` has is a scroll view), or hacking system navigation bar (in which either the buttons are aligned to the bottom, or it uses private iOS frameworks which is a forbidden fruit, we know it). I also tried to add the segmented control to the `tableHeaderView`, but it is consumed by the search bar.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: It is possible to do this. Apple does this in App Store. Also looking to find out how.

Comment: Apple does this with a nasty hack in the App Store. Just see how it behaves when you do the back swipe gesture slowly.