# Removing the hairline under Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitoolbar

The effect that I want to achieve is:

[image]

And the current state of my app is:

[image]

This is the set up of my view controller. I put a tool bar underneath the navigation bar. Then, I set the tool bar's delegate to the navigation bar. I've read several posts about this. One solution that was provided was:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage();
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

However, this causes the navigation bar to become white and loses the effect. So I got the following code from this post ([UISegmentedControl below UINavigationbar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887252/uisegmentedcontrol-below-uinavigationbar-in-ios-7)):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    var hairLine: UIView = UIView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        doneButton.enabled = false

        for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
            for childView in parent.subviews {
                if childView is UIImageView && childView.bounds.size.width == self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.width {
                    hairLine = childView
                    print(hairLine.frame)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func removeHairLine(appearing: Bool) {
        var hairLineFrame = hairLine.frame
        if appearing {
            hairLineFrame.origin.y += toolbar.bounds.size.height
        } else {
            hairLineFrame.origin.y -= toolbar.bounds.size.height
        }
        hairLine.frame = hairLineFrame
        print(hairLine.frame)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        removeHairLine(true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        removeHairLine(true)
    }
```

However, this code removes the hairline before the view is completely loaded but when the view is loaded, it appears again. Any solutions?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution on this site but don't remember where exactly.

Objective-C:

```
@interface YourViewController () {
  UIImageView *navBarHairlineImageView;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  navBarHairlineImageView = [self findHairlineImageViewUnder:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
  navBarHairlineImageView.hidden = YES;
}

- (UIImageView *)findHairlineImageViewUnder:(UIView *)view {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class] && view.bounds.size.height <= 1.0) {
    return (UIImageView *)view;
  }
  for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
      UIImageView *imageView = [self findHairlineImageViewUnder:subview];
      if (imageView) {
          return imageView;
      }
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Swift:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var navBarLine: UIImageView?

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navBarLine = findHairlineImageViewUnderView(self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
        navBarLine?.hidden = true
    }

    func findHairlineImageViewUnderView(view: UIView?) -> UIImageView? {
        if view.isKindOfClass(UIImageView.classForCoder()) && view.bounds.height <= 1 {
            return view as? UIImageView
        }
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let imgView = findHairlineImageViewUnderView(subview) {
                return imgView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... There seems to be some errors with the code... It's not compiling on my end and it seems that there are some misspelling involved as well...

Answer (score 1):

I use this lines of code

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "background"), for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
 for childView in parent.subviews {
     if(childView is UIImageView) {
         childView.removeFromSuperview()
     }
 }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[0].subviews.filter({$0 is UIImageView})[0].removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any good Swift 3 solution so I am adding this one, based on [Ivan Bruel answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36982373/1162044) His solution is protocol oriented, allows to hide hairline in any view controller with just one line of code and without subclassing.

Add this code to your views model:

```
protocol HideableHairlineViewController {

  func hideHairline()
  func showHairline()
}

extension HideableHairlineViewController where Self: UIViewController {

  func hideHairline() {
    findHairline()?.isHidden = true
  }

  func showHairline() {
    findHairline()?.isHidden = false
  }

  private func findHairline() -> UIImageView? {
    return navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
      .flatMap { $0.subviews }
      .flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }
      .filter { $0.bounds.size.width == self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.size.width }
      .filter { $0.bounds.size.height <= 2 }
      .first
  }

}
```

Then make sure view controller which doesn't need hairline conforms to `HideableHairlineViewController` protocol and call `hideHairline()`.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4 version of [alexandr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453029/4940845) answer

#### Step 1: Create property of type `UIImageView?`

```
private var navigationBarHairLine: UIImageView?
```

#### Step 2: Create `findHairlineImageViewUnderView` function

> This function filters through the view's subviews to find the view with the height of less than or equal to 1pt.

```
func findHairlineImageViewUnderView(view: UIView?) -> UIImageView? { 
    guard let view = view else { return nil } 
    if view.isKind(of: UIImageView.classForCoder()) && view.bounds.height <= 1 { 
        return view as? UIImageView 
    } 
    for subView in view.subviews { 
        if let imageView = findHairlineImageViewUnderView(view: subView) { 
            return imageView 
        } 
    } 
    return nil 
}
```

#### Step 3: Call the created function in `ViewWillAppear` and pass in the navigationBar. It will return the hairline view which you then set as hidden.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    navigationBarHairLine = findHairlineImageViewUnderView(view: navigationController?.navigationBar) 
    navigationBarHairLine?.isHidden = true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UINavigationBar and set the following in initializer (Swift 5):

```
shadowImage = UIImage()
setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default) // needed for iOS 10
```

E.g.:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }


    private func setupViews() {
        shadowImage = UIImage()
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default) // needed for iOS 10
    }

}
```