# Custom UINavigationBar items position

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have custom `UINavigationBar` and it's currently look like this:

[image]

I want to make the bar items at top position and the `UISegmentControl`at the bottom.

I try so far this in `layoutSubviews` method:

```
    NSArray *classNamesToReposition = @[@"UINavigationButton"];

    for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {

        if ([classNamesToReposition containsObject:NSStringFromClass([view class])]) {

            CGRect frame = [view frame];
            frame.origin.y -= 100;

            [view setFrame:frame];
        }
    }
```

But I feel like it's a hack and not the proper way (since `UINavigationButton` is private API :/ )

How can I make the bar items not stick to the bottom on the `UINavigationBar`?

Note:
I m aware of [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: y u r not tried with navigation bar with scope bar

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I didn't understand your comment

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I would like navigation bar like Apple's Health app https://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/DBEUN7QACePB2O40ajVjDKuvl2Y=/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/1396490/IMG_0055.0.PNG

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887252/uisegmentedcontrol-below-uinavigationbar-in-ios-7