# How set navigation bar title with segment controller in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, sap-btp-sdk-ios

How can i achieve like this [image]

in `UITableView` controller not in `UIViewController`.

here i'm using SAP Fiori component for design.

So far i tried ui form `storybard` using navigation bar prompt:[image]

here is the code so far i tried:

```
      self.navigationController?.makeBlackNavigationbar()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.makeBlackNavigationBar()
        let items = ["Label A", "Label B"]
        segmentedController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        segmentedController.frame = (self.navigationController?.toolbar.bounds)!
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(segmentedController)

     extension UINavigationController
     {
      func makeBlackNavigationbar (){

        print("black navigation")

        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
      }
    }

    extension UINavigationBar
    { 

      func makeBlackNavigationBar ()
      {
        barTintColor = UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 94/255, blue: 117/255, alpha: 1)
        let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        titleTextAttributes = titleDict as [NSObject : AnyObject] as! [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]



       }
     }
```

Any help much appreciated pls..

Comment: see this for help : [UISegmentedControl below UINavigationbar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887252/uisegmentedcontrol-below-uinavigationbar-in-ios-7/21999916)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can u check my tried screenshot..

Answer (score 0):

> How can i achieve like this

You can't. You can have the segmented control *as* the title view, *replacing* the title text; but you cannot have *both* a segmented control as the title view *and* title text.

The only way to get something like the first screenshot would be through an elaborate illusion. You'd need to have the segmented control *outside* the navigation bar, as part of the main view, but surrounded by a view that *looks* like the navigation bar and melds into it (because the navigation bar itself has no visible bottom edge or shadow).